# how to find a word in python

Tags: python, file, search

Im trying to search and find a correct word in a file

```
 file = ('data.bin', '+r')
 Filefind = file.read()
 f = raw_input("search a word: ")
 While f in Filefind:
        print "this word is found!"
```

This code actually find the word I have entered, but it find the word even if it's not fully entered
For example, if I have "findme" word in the file, script will find it if I enter only "fi" in raw_input

How to write a script that returns me True, if it finds the full word in a file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `regex` with word boundaries:

```
import re
def search(word, text):
    return bool(re.search(r'\b{}\b'.format(re.escape(word)), text))
... 
>>> search("foo", "foobar foospam")
False
>>> search("foo", "foobar foo")
True
```

Comment: Please explane me how to use this regext on a file, I have never used them in Python

Comment: @Streak What's the issue? Simply pass the content of the file and the word you're searching to this function.

Comment: Ok, but im getting the following error: 'str' object has no attribute 'format'